# How to avoid scale a background drawable

Tags: android, android-drawable

My start activity has theme `@style/AppTheme.Launcher`

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:opacity="opaque">

    <item android:drawable="@color/colorPrimary" />

    <item>
        <bitmap android:src="@drawable/my_logo" android:gravity="center" />
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

When my activity is start I get an error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: my.package, PID: 23108
              java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{ru.package/my.package.MainActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Drawable my.package:drawable/launch_screen with resource ID #0x7f060059
```

#### UPDATE 1

```
<resources>

    ...

    <style name="AppTheme.Launcher" parent="AppTheme">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/launch_screen</item>
    </style>


</resources>
```

My activity starts with this theme.

Comment: Post your design XML file

Comment: @MayurPatel updated

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
<item>
    <bitmap android:src="@drawable/my_logo" android:gravity="center" />
</item>
```

try:

```
<item>
    <bitmap  app:srcCompat="@drawable/my_logo" android:gravity="center" />
</item>
```

or:

```
<item
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/my_logo" android:gravity="center" />
```

Are you sure that `launch_screen.xml` is in `res/drawable` folder in your main package?  
 Have you created different folders like `drawable-v21`?  
The error message is:

```
Resources$NotFoundException: Drawable my.package:drawable/launch_screen
```

if `launch_screen.xml` was there where it should be your app would work fine.  
Last resort: clean and rebuild your project.

Comment: If I set `<item android:drawable="@drawable/my_logo" />` instead `<item><bitmap android:src="@drawable/my_logo" android:gravity="center" /></item>` everything is ok except stretch image

Comment: If I put `my_logo.png` instead `my_logo.xml`everything is ok

Answer (score 0):

You can use `drawable` to add an image inside the `layer - list`. try this, Hope this will help you. If not let me know.

```
<layer-list
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@color/colorPrimary" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/home_background" />
</layer-list>
```

Comment: It's not work. It says [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource#LayerList)  **To avoid scaling, the following example uses a <bitmap> element with centered gravity**